# React-Native Shake Event Detector With Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, shake

> I'm using `Expo v2.3.8` and `Expo client v2.9.0` on iOS phone.

I'm trying to test shake `addEventListener` event but always end up Expo developer menu opens. So I closed the shake option in Expo but this time when I shake, the phone old Expo developer menu opens.

Here is my code :

```
import RNShake from 'react-native-shake';

export default class Starting extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'MyApp',
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      RNShake.addEventListener('shake', () => {
        this.props.navigation.push('Register');
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      RNShake.removeEventListener('shake');
    }
   .
   . 
   .
}
```

I tried turn on production mode. It didnt work. 
How can I test shake event with Expo? 
React Native Shake Detector - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shake

Answer (score 0):

The `react-native-shake` library requires linking native code, so it will not work without first ejecting from Expo to Expokit as explained here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/

From your project directory, run `expo eject`. This will download the required dependencies and build native projects under the ios and android directories. Then run `react-native link react-native-shake` as per the library install instructions.

Comment: Could you provide a solution / short description along with link?

Comment: Not for me in the comment, edit the answer, please :)